# Can a Frightened Controlled Mount Be Made to Move Closer to the Source of Its Fear?

Tags: dnd-5e, mount, fear

The Frightened condition states that a Frightened creature cannot willingly move closer to the source of its fear.

If a mount is being controlled by a rider who is not Frightened, can the rider make the mount move closer to the source of its fear?

Answer (score 4):

### You should regain control of the mount before being able to make it move closer to the source of its fear.

As stated in PHB, page 178:

> **Animal Handling.** When there is any question whether you can calm down a domesticated animal, keep a mount from getting spooked, or intuit an animal's intentions, the DM might call for a Wisdom (Animal Handling) check. You also make a Wisdom (Animal Handling) check to control your mount when you attempt a risky maneuver.

From page 198:

> **CONTROLLING A MOUNT**. While you're mounted, you have two options. You can either control the mount or allow it to act
> independently.(...)
> An independent mount retains its place in the
> initiative order. (...)

Also, from Appendix A, Conditions, page 291:

> A condition lasts either until it is countered
> (the prone condition is countered by standing
> up, for example) or for a duration specified by the effect
> that imposed the condition.

> **FRIGHTENED** A frightened creature has disadvantage on ability checks and attack rolls while the source of its fear is within line of sight. The creature can't willingly move closer to the source of its fear

Your mount cannot move **willingly** to the source of its fear until the frightening condition is countered as long as you are allowing your mount to act independently.

I understand that **if a mount is under the Frightened condition it is *not* *Controlled*** and is therefore acting independently, since it would resist moving towards a specific direction, in this case the source if its fear. To be able to make it move closer **you must counter the Frightenend condition**, which is something the Rider could do.

Here is how I would address the matter:

By the rider's choice, it can be controlled with a Wisdom (Animal Handling) check at a DC set by your DM. If the check is successful, the mount would be back under control (or maybe, as stated in the comments, the mount would be allowed a saving throw with advantage, but I find this approach redundant, although is is indeed more realistic), thus ending the Frightened condition. This check would use your action for the turn. A controlled mount shares initiative count with its rider, so immediately after ending the Frightened condition, you could move the mount freely again.

Comment: At the DM's discretion, if there is a save at some point, then an Animal Handling check could be made (DM chooses the DC). If it passes, I would allow the mount to have a saving throw with advantage.

Comment: @QnanG5284, Is your argument that a controlled mount could be made to move closer because its movement wouldn't be considered "willing"?  Would you mind restructuring this answer to make your claim clearer, and perhaps focusing in more on the question? There is stuff here that I don't find to be relevant, like the block quote about falling off the mount, the last line about dismounting as a reaction, or the block quote about ending conditions. Also, from my perspective, you can fully assume controlled mount, and so wouldn't need to consider uncontrolled mounts in the answer. TY!

Comment: Restructured the answer.

Comment: I've re-written some text to make my point even clearer.

Answer (score -2):

## Rules as written you could make the mount move closer. But...

**Control**: as defined in the [Merriam Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/control):

> 1. to direct the behavior of (a person or animal) : to cause (a person or animal) to do what you want

and the relevant rules text for mounted combat says:

> You can control a mount only if it has been trained to accept a rider. Domesticated horses, donkeys, and similar Creatures are assumed to have such Training. The Initiative of a controlled mount changes to match yours when you mount it. It *moves as you direct it*, and it has only three action options: Dash, Disengage, and Dodge.

(emphasis mine). By the defintion of the word control, you cause the animal to do what *you* want. Its own will does not come into play. This is further supported by the mechanistic execution of the situation: the creature loses its own position in the initiative order, and the text explicitly states that that it moves as you direct.

The relevant part for the [Frightened](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Rules:Conditions#content) condition is:

> **Frightened** The creature can’t *willingly* move closer to the source of its fear.

As it only *willingly cannot* move, but its will does not matter while controlled, you could move it closer.

### Munchinism

**Is this realistic? No.** For horses in real life there is *no way* to make a frightened mount do what you want because you "control" it. If the horse gets frightened it will jump or bolt or stop, and you will have to work to regain actual control.

One could allow a successful *Animal Handling* check to end the frightened condition to represent this. Making a skill check consumes an action, and if you first are not successful, it may take you several rounds to calm down your horse.

A [munchkin](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50059/how-to-ease-down-the-munchkin-factor) is:

> A player who concentrates solely on increasing his character's power and capabilities.

Often this is done by insisting on interpreting the rules in a literal way, even if the results lead to absurd results, or do not make much sense from a storytelling perspective. I'm not saying this is neccesarily bad, but it is a very different kind of game.

To me, it seems that insisting on the RAW interpretation here will make the character more powerful -- their horse now cannot be frightened any more -- and goes in this direction.

These questions are often not easy to answer -- our own group has plenty of disucssion about when it is fair to go off the rules for "that is how it *should* work vs. when not.

### Why the rules do not cover this

Keep in mind that the **rules are an abstraction**. The rules primarily aim to enable play, they do not aim to *simulate* the real world. They cannot cover all specific situations that could arise, or they would become so long that they would be useless. Here is the take from the [Sage Advice](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice) Rules companion, that counts as official rules:

> The DM is key. Many unexpected things can happen in a D&D campaign, and no set of rules could reasonably account for every contingency. If the rules tried to do so, the game would become unplayable.

> The direction we chose for the current edition was to lay a foundation of rules that a DM could build on, and we embraced the DM’s role as the bridge between the things the rules address and the things they don’t.

The rules for controlling a mount simplify combat. In a normal combat situation that does not cause issues, and speeds up play for a better experience.

The situation the rule represents is *mundane*. The control is not supernatural, there is no sorcery that compells the horse. A peasant boy with riding skills could mount and control a horse.

With the skill not being magical, if you want verisimilitude, what happens in game should work as it would in the real world. In the unusual situation not explicitly covered by the rules, the GM would be fully in his rights to make a ruling that you cannot make a *frightened* horse move closer to the source of its fright.

What's more, most sources of the *frightened* condition are supernatual -- typcially spells like [Fear](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fear) or monsters like a [dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/adult-red-dragon) cause it. In the face of such forces, the normal rules of behaviour seem even more unlikely to apply.

### What should you do?

Therefore my **But...**: I think that insisting on the rules as written in this instance would create a mechanistic, tabletop tactics battle experience, while interpreting the situation based on real-world behaviour would create a more immersive, role-playing experience. Depending on what game they prefer, your GM could rule either way.

Comment: As far as the movement goes, is your argument that a controlled mount's movement isn't "willing"?

Comment: If you want control to override Frightened, the horse makes no decisions and there is no willing or not, the rider decides as RAW. But I think that is not a good mechanic if you want a believable world. I as GM would rule that this is technical sophistry and not allow it.

Comment: @DanJurgella Hi Dan, your comment showed that my answer was not clear. I revised it, so that the answer is in the actual answer, not in the comment.